# Without expanding, show that $\left| \begin{smallmatrix} 3&4&5 \\ 15&21&26 \\ 21&29&36 \\ \end{smallmatrix}\right|=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Without expanding,prove that:
$$\left|
\begin{matrix}
3&4&5 \\
15&21&26 \\
21&29&36 \\
\end{matrix}\right|=0$$

My Attempt:

> $$L.H.S.=
> \begin{vmatrix}
>   3 & 4 & 5 \\
>   15 & 21 & 26 \\
>   21 & 29 & 36 \\
> \end{vmatrix}
> $$
>   Packing common "$3$" from the first column:
>   $$=3
> \begin{vmatrix}
>   1 & 4 & 5 \\
>   5 & 21 & 26 \\
>   7 & 29 & 36 \\
> \end{vmatrix}
> $$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Row3=Row2+2*Row1. Hence, determinant is zero.

Comment: Or simpler still Col1+Col2=Col3

Answer (score 8):

Great start! The next thing you want to look at is a single column operation, which should give you the result straight away.